# Was there ever a time that you Spent Quest Points for Hints on Different Quests in Runescape?

Tags: runescape

I specifically remember a time where there was this website you can go into and you were allowed to spend Quest points to receive hints to different quests you are currently on. Is this true, If so, what was the website/context, or is my old mind playing tricks on me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're thinking of was [QuestHelp](https://runescape.wiki/w/QuestHelp), a system that helped players who were stuck during quests. The currency itself was not quest points, but another type of points where you get 4 a day:

> Each player had 4 QuestHelp points, which were reset after 24 hours.
> Using these points, players could unlock:
>
> - Hints - cost a point each. Unlocked by clicking "Reveal Hint" on the
>   parchment
> - Spoilers - cost two points each. Unlocked by clicking
>   "Reveal Spoiler" on the parchment.

Answer (score 4):

While I don't personally remember there being such a thing for OSRS, there does appear to be a news post from back in 2018 (for RuneScape 3) regarding spending quest points. Specifically, a Quest Point Shop.

https://secure.runescape.com/m=news/quest-point-shop

> Greetings!
>
> So, you’re all sitting on loads and loads of quest points, right? Or
> perhaps you’ve not delved too deep down the questing rabbit hole
> because, why bother, as you can’t do anything with those points
> anyway? Whichever is true for you, we have good news – Quest Point
> Shop is here to reward questers for their heroic deeds!
>
> WHAT IS IT? As the name might suggest, Quest Point Shop is… a shop.
> More specifically, a shop in which you can spend quest points. Quest
> points + shop = Quest Point Shop. We hope you’re keeping up. You’ll be
> able to find it south west of the Varrock Lodestone.
>
> In the shop players will find May. She’s a tinkerer, so please do
> excuse any mess you find around her wagon. May used to be an
> adventurer herself, and is determined to help other adventurers
> succeed in their pursuits. Well done her!
>
> In Quest Point Shop there is one general reward track and then a
> number of additional reward tracks that players can choose to progress
> along, should they so desire. The former is automatic, but the latter
> depends on how the player chooses to allocate their points.
>
> WHAT CAN YOU GET? Quest Point Shop unlocks occur in 25 quest point
> intervals, and players will be able to reset their unlocks once a
> week.

I also found a reference to May's Quest Caravan, here:

https://www.runehq.com/special/mays-quest-caravan

> Located next to the Champions’ Guild, just South West of the Varrock
> lodestone, is May’s Quest Caravan. Here you can use your quest points
> to obtain special offers and rewards for completing a certain number
> of quests. You will also find the Quest Noticeboard which informs you
> who has completed what quest most recently.
>
> First and foremost, you will need to complete 1 or more quest to begin
> taking advantage of what May has to offer.

Perhaps this is what you remembered?